# How to map object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm trying to map an array of objects with "x" properties, to display these properties in a html table, for a system report page. But, it returns a single string with all properties, and for all objects, so it dont allow me styling each of these properties... the idea is set "space-between" to show below a header.
OBS: using react-js.

```js
<Text style={styles.infos}>
      {Test.map(item => {
          let keys = Object.keys(item);
          return keys.map(key => item[key]);
      })}
</Text>
```

Example of how it's working:
`[{"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"},{"d": "d", "e": "e", "f": "f"},{"g": "g", "h": "h", "i": "i"}]`
Expected: `<div><p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p></div>, 
<div><p>d</p><p>e</p><p>f</p></div>, 
<div><p>g</p><p>h</p><p>i</p></div>`
Actual: `<div><p>abcdefghi</p></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"},{"d": "d", "e": "e", "f": "f"},{"g": "g", "h": "h", "i": "i"}];

let res = arr.map(a=> {return `<div>${ Object.keys(a).map(k => { return `<p>${a[k]}</p>` }) }</div>`})



console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join Array with `''` space after `Object.keys()`

```
<Text style={styles.infos}>
      {Test.map(item => (<p>{Object.keys(item).join('')}<p>))}
</Text>
```

```js
let arr = [{"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"},{"d": "d", "e": "e", "f": "f"},{"g": "g", "h": "h", "i": "i"}];

let res = arr.map(a=> Object.keys(a).join(''))

console.log(res)
```